# Stripe using Cloud Firestore. Stripe.setPublishableKey command not found

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use Stripe in my app with Cloud Firestore as the backend. Following this example, I make it to:
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe

Pass your Stripe publishable key to the Stripe.setPublishableKey call in public/index.html

But I'm getting the error:

-bash :command not found.  Looks like I'm implementing the line incorrectly. Any help?

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey<myKey>
```

Comment: Where are you trying to run that command?

Comment: @floatingLomas In the terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not something you'd do via the command line; it's something you'd do in the public/index.html file: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/stripe/public/index.html#L113

I see you tagged this as `swift` which probably means you're trying to use this for an iOS app, so this example as it stands won't really work for you.  You'll need to combine it (at least conceptually, since the languages are different) with this one: https://github.com/stripe/example-mobile-backend